# Learning Spring 4 and JEE 7?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Is it worth to start learning Spring 4 or JEE 7 now? If I recall correctly, a new version of JEE is coming by the end of 2017, Spring is going to be released shortly after JDK 9, due in July(?). Yet, certainly, no available books describe the incoming versions.

Are incoming Spring 5 and JEE 8 going to be incremental releases that do not invalidate the basic functionality of Spring 4 and JEE7?

Comment: Both have quite a long history of backward compatibility, and the principles behind them will very likely remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core functionalities and principles will stay the same. What will change is probably some removal of old code (in Spring 5), which you won't even notice if you learn Spring 4.3 now, as well as new APIs which will simplify development.

The most important thing is: Learn and understand the principles and basic APIs (dependency injection, persistence handling, application deployment etc.). Also, in IT if you wait to learn something because the new version is just a few weeks away, you will never learn anything new.